# Can I repeat slow cluster node jobs at the end of a gnu parallel job for faster completion

Tags: gnu-parallel

At the end of processing a large suite of jobs on an inhomogeneous cluster it is highly likely that the slowest node will still be processing its last job while the fastest nodes will be idle. If there are orders of magnitude difference in job processing times between nodes, then this could result in a significant loss of time.

Is there a way for nodes, which become idle once all jobs have been distributed, to be assigned replicate jobs for those not yet returned?

I see the `--resume-failed` option but this isnt exactly what I want. It's not that the slow node has failed to process a job *per se*. It's that a fast node, that has become idle at the end of the set of jobs, could do the job of the slowest node before the slowest node completes.

I assume that this isnt already the default behaviour of gnu-parallel because I can add a very slow node to my cluster resulting in a much slower (orders of magnitude) overall processing time.

Comment: Can you anticipate/estimate the size/complexity of jobs in advance at all - maybe you could start the biggest jobs first on the fastest processors. Or maybe you could use GNU Parallel in a *"job queue"* mode and be a bit ore tactical about how/when you submit jobs to the queue. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes but, the general issue I'm trying to articulate, is one of similar jobs, but on an ad hoc cluster. One in which, a very slow node may usefully process a job or two, where the bulk of jobs are done by faster nodes Then the slow nodes 'hang' the system at the end of the process. In the case of an ad hoc system with a large number of similar jobs but a wide variation in node processing speed this would be a common occurance and unlikely to be solved by those tactical job allocation solutions unfortunately. What's needed is the ability to kill/pull the slow nodes at the end of the process.

Comment: I wonder if a combination of --timeout 200% and --resume-failed would work? @Ole Tange?